# Can a Bladesinger wizard cast Shillelagh, Magic Stone, or Mending with their Extra Attack feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, spellcasting, cantrips

The [Bladesinging wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Bladesinging)'s [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ExtraAttack-526) feature reads:

> You can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. Moreover, you can cast one of your cantrips in place of one of those attacks.

Notably, all but three cantrips have a casting time of 1 action. Two cantrips, *shillelagh* and *magic stone*, have a casting time of 1 bonus action, and the cantrip *mending* has a casting time of 1 minute.

Can these cantrips be cast with the Bladesinger's Extra Attack feature, despite not having a casting time of 1 action?
If *mending* in particular can be cast in this way, does it take effect immediately? Or does it still take a minute to complete casting?

(Never mind how our Wizard learned *shillelagh* or *magic stone*; perhaps they took a 1 level dip into druid when they went hiking during a gap year in their studies.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

Compare that phrasing to the third benefit of the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) feat (PHB, p. 170):

> When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. **The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.**

You can see that it specifies what type of cantrip you can cast, with the limitations of needing to have a normal casting time of 1 action, and also only targeting the creature that provoked the opportunity attack. It effectively limits your options to mostly just offensive cantrips.

Notably, the Bladesinger's Extra Attack feature *lacks* any language that restricts what type of cantrip you can cast. It simply states that "you can cast one of your cantrips". Obviously, the *intent* was for you to cast an attack cantrip, such as *booming blade* or *fire bolt*, but this ability has been worded poorly, and allows for *any* cantrip to be cast, including ones that normally have a casting time of "1 bonus action" or "1 minute".

In the case of *mending*, it should go into effect immediately, although the benefits of casting *mending* in the middle of combat are few, unless you have an Artificer ally with an Eldritch Cannon, Steel Defender, or Homunculus Servant in need of repair.

---

If I were the DM in this situation, I would restrict it to only cantrips with a casting time of 1 action, and disallow things like the examples you provided. I would still allow non-offensive cantrips, as I like to reward creative uses of spells.

Comment: Notably the *mending* cantrip doesn't *have* to be mid-combat. Simply take the Attack action outside of combat for an instant *mending*. It also may help to compare the Extra Attack feature to features that *do* restrict what types of spells/cantrips they use

Comment: @Medix2 I just figured out why slamming a TV with your bare fists will fix it...

Comment: Why would you stop bonus action cantrips? They are closer to 'half action' in speed than full action cantrips, and the power makes no mention of cast time at all. Though I can understand why mending is an odd one out.

Comment: @Medix2 Outside of combat, time is usually much less of a constraint. 3-4 minutes spent casting *Mending* vs 3-4 rounds will hardly make a difference.

Comment: This could make for some shenanigans if the Autognome (UA) is published as is. Healing yourself with mending mid-fight is pretty nifty. I suppose an Artificer can do the same to their pet, though it's a pretty deep dip.

Comment: Funnily enough, casting *shillelagh* / *magic stone* in this way would still prevent you from casting *any* spell with your bonus action...

Answer (score -2):

### No, you cant.

I know this is an old question with an accepted answer, but I am coming in to highlight that the accepted answer is missing important details and is not, in fact, how the abilities would interact.

First, to reiterate

> You can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. **Moreover, you can cast one of your cantrips in place of one of those attacks.**

The important thing here is that it's just saying you can cast. There is no distinction on cast time, and there doesn't need to be, because of the rules on spellcasting and specifically [spells with longer cast times](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#LongerCastingTimes) (PHB, p. 203):

> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to cast: minutes or even hours. **When you cast a spell with a casting time longer than a single action or reaction, you must spend your action each turn casting the spell,** and you must maintain your concentration while you do so. If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don’t expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over.

This means that your bladesinger extra attack feature can cast *one action* worth of the spell, but if you wish to complete casting the spell, you must continue to either use your action (or your extra attack action) each turn until the cast time has been satisfied, and for these longer duration spells like *mending*, combat will usually be over by then.  Plus, you're probably going to be concentrating on more important things.

Comment: You aren't using your action to cast the cantrips with a casting time of 1 action though. The bladesinger's feature circumvents the action cost of those cantrips, so why not the action cost of these others?

Comment: Because it specifically doesn't circumvent the action cost. The specific text is "you can cast [the] cantrip in place one of [your] attacks". That's it. Cast. And the text on casting a spell that takes longer than 1 action is that you have to cast it each turn until the cast time is met. Mending still takes a minute to cast, but a bladesinger has the added benefit of being able to weave attacks in during that minute other classes wouldn't be able to.

Comment: But the text on casting a spell also says you have to use your action if the casting time is one action.